# How to automatically mount at boot?

Tags: linux, mount, loop-device

I have a file, called "some.img", created with `fallocate`, that has a filesystem on it. I can mount the img file using `mount -o loop some.img /media/where`, and I see the filesystem. When I reboot, however, the file is no longer mounted.

How do I automatically mount this at boot?

**Update**: SuSE Linux

Comment: https://www.binarytides.com/ubuntu-automatically-mount-partition-startup/ may be helpful if you are using Ubuntu or a derivative. Perhaps you could click on [edit] and tell us which *ix you use, by adding that to your original question?

Comment: Yeah, @Kusalananda, it solved my problem. But man was this answer hard to look for. I didn't really know that I needed to look for "loop device permanence" because my symptoms were that my mount (whatever it was I dunno) was disappearing after a reboot.

Comment: @activedecay I search this site for "loop device permanently"... it was the 1st hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, add the following to `/etc/fstab`:

```
/path/to/file       /path/to/mount       ext4       loop       0 0
```

As described in
https://superuser.com/questions/799162/permanent-loop-device